# Looping through array with a while comparison

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to loop through and array and while incrementing a value.

Here is my code.

```
#!/bin/bash -e

# set -x

GASLIMIT=8000000
LIMIT=268435456000000 
VM_FAMILY_ARRAY=(t2.xlarge t2.2xlarge t3a.xlarge t3a.2xlarge a1.4xlarge a1.metal m4.xlarge m4.2xlarge m5.4xlarge  m5.8xlarge m5.12xlarge m5.16xlarge m5.24xlarge m5.metal)


for i in "${VM_FAMILY_ARRAY[@]}"
do
    while [ $GASLIMIT -le "$LIMIT" ]
        do 
            echo "$i""$GASLIMIT"
            GASLIMIT=$(($GASLIMIT*2))
        done

done
```

I would like script's output to look like this:

```
t2.xlarge8000000
<!--SNIP-->
t2.xlarge268435456000000
m5.metal8000000
<!-SNIP->
m5.metal268435456000000
```

What I am getting right now is just the first member of the VM_FAMILY array (t2.xlarge) with the script exiting once it has reached `$LIMIT`

```
t2.xlarge8000000
t2.xlarge16000000
<!--SNIP-->
t2.xlarge67108864000000
t2.xlarge134217728000000
t2.xlarge268435456000000
```

I would appreciate pointers on this

Comment: Try resetting GASLIMIT inside the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GASLIMIT` variable is not reset to its "base" value inside your for loop.

Hence, after your first `for` iteration, `GASLIMIT` is already greater than `LIMIT` and your `while` loop never run.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

set -eu

LIMIT=268435456000000 
VM_FAMILY_ARRAY=(t2.xlarge t2.2xlarge t3a.xlarge t3a.2xlarge a1.4xlarge a1.metal m4.xlarge m4.2xlarge m5.4xlarge  m5.8xlarge m5.12xlarge m5.16xlarge m5.24xlarge m5.metal)

for i in "${VM_FAMILY_ARRAY[@]}"
do
    GASLIMIT=8000000
    while [ $GASLIMIT -le "$LIMIT" ]
        do 
            echo "$i""$GASLIMIT"
            GASLIMIT=$(($GASLIMIT*2))
        done
done
```